# using schwarz inequality to prove convergence of sum

Tags: calculus, inequality, convergence-divergence

If I want to show that if $\sum a_k^2$ and $\sum b_k^2$ converge then $\sum a_kb_k$ converges.  Would it be a clear proof to first show that the sum $\sum (a_K^2 + b_k^2)$ converges then to point out that, since the question is restricted to non-negative terms, $\sum \dfrac{1}{2}(a_K^2 + b_k^2)$ is less than the sum earlier shown to be convergent, and then to apply the schwarz inequlity to $\sum |a_kb_k|$ to show that this is less than the last written inequality, and of course pointing out basic comparision to indicate the lesser sums are convergent.  and to finally statte that the if the absolute value of a sum is convergent then so is the original sum?

Comment: Yup, that's the usual way. Mind you, your base field has to be complete for the last argument.

Comment: "base field has to be complete". I'm not quite sure what you're referring to by this

Comment: Absolute convergence implies convergence when the space is complete for the norm used, which means that every Cauchy verifying sequence is convergent. This is not the case for example for field $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Ah, this makes sense.  Thanks for the feedback!